# Value from dropdown hides/shows div (using Javascript and Ruby on Rails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, haml

I've been trying to implement what should be a pretty simple feature, but I'm not having much luck. I have a drop-down menu on my ROR app which prompts the user to Select a Country.

NOTE: The list of Countries is contained in the Constants.rb file (but basically the two available options are: Interantional and United States.)

What I would like to see happen: When a user selects "United States" the div id state_nav (a div containing a drop-down menu with a list of States) would show up... if the user selects International, the state_nav menu would remain hidden.

Here is what I had thus far in terms of code (I'm using HAML)

The javascript is located in the header of the html

```
:javascript
  function showDiv(obj)
  {
      if(obj[obj.selectedIndex].value == 'United States')
      {
          document.getElementById('state_div').style.display = 'block';
      }
      else
      {
          document.getElementById('state_div').style.display = 'none';
      }
  }
```

this is the code located in the body of the html.HAML

```
  .section
    %div{:class => "label_leftalign field"}
        %p.information
          please list the country, state (if applicable), and city where you're located
        = f.label :country, "Location"
        = f.select :country, COUNTRIES, :onChange => "showDiv(this)", :prompt => true

    %div{:class => "label_leftalign field"}
      #state_div{:style => "display:none;"}
          = f.label :state, "&nbsp;".html_safe
          = f.select :state, STATES, :prompt => true
```

At present... when I load the page it the State drop-down (#state_div) is hidden, and it remains hidden regardless of what Country is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would change :onChange to :onchange. Then throw an alert into your js to see if the JS is at least being called:

```
:javascript
  function showDiv(obj)
  {
      alert(obj[obj.selectedIndex].value);
      if(obj[obj.selectedIndex].value == 'United States')
      {
          document.getElementById('state_div').style.display = 'block';
      }
      else
      {
          document.getElementById('state_div').style.display = 'none';
      }
  }
```

UPDATED:

You can change your select to include missing hash param:

```
.section
  %div{:class => "label_leftalign field"}
      %p.information
        please list the country, state (if applicable), and city where you're located
      = f.label :country, "Location"
      = f.select :country, COUNTRIES, {}, :onChange => "showDiv(this)", :prompt => true
  %div{:class => "label_leftalign field"}
    #state_div{:style => "display:none;"}
        = f.label :state, "&nbsp;".html_safe
        = f.select :state, STATES, :prompt => true
```

I tried that on my local and it worked. Make sure that the value of your option field reflects that value that you are asserting in obj[obj.selectedIndex].value.

Comment: I am using Jquery... unfortunately changing :onChange to :onchange did not help.

Comment: Revised answer to use collection_select

Comment: Hm... unfortunately, that did not seem to work. I definitely have the correct value (United States), as a matter of fact here is the code in my constants.rb:

COUNTRIES = ['United States', 'International']

Unfortunately, it's still not working for some reason. I really appreciate your help Chris... thank you!

Comment: When you add that alert line in your js, do you get the right value popping up? alert(obj[obj.selectedIndex].value);

Comment: Chris, where would that value pop-up?

Comment: If you js was firing correctly and you stuck that line in the spot illustrated above, then the alert should popup as a box on top of your browser anytime you changed the value in your pulldown. If you don't see an alert, then your js is not firing correctly.

Comment: I'm getting the following error in rails: undefined method `name' for "United States":String

Comment: Ah. I just assumed that the COUNTRIES and STATES were models with the fields id and name. You can try using your original f.select and leave the alert in to see what you get.

Comment: Then your js is not getting called when you do your select. If you use firebug in your browser (if you are using firefox), do you see the onchange attribute being rendered in the the select tag?

Comment: I'm at a loss why the onChange attribute is not being rendered. ANy ideas??

Comment: you try the lower case one? :onchange =>

Comment: I tried out the above and you are missing an argument to differentiate between options and html_options. Answer above should work

Comment: Chris, thank you so much! You are right... it's working brilliantly now! I really, really appreciate all of your help!

Comment: No problem dude. Good luck with your project.